# Why Laravel method call twice when using route()->redirect with parameters & code 301?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-7

Please help me, I don't know why Laravel method is called twice times when I use command this command to redirect to new page:

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/editor/create/{productCode}', 'EditorController@create')->name('create-new-design');
Route::get('/editor/{designCode}', 'EditorController@edit')->name('edit-design');
```

**EditorController:**

```
public function create($productCode) {
    // .. do some thing & redirect to editor page
    return redirect()->route('edit-design', ['designCode' => $newDesignCode], 301);
}

public function edit($designCode){
    // this method is called twice

    $design = Design::where('code', '=', $designCode)->first();

    // do extra options --> return editor edit view
    return view('editor.edit');
}
```

**Flow:**
User request to create new Design by call action [POST]: /editor/create/{productCode} --> Server process & create Design Record then redirect user to editor page ( --> /editor/{designCode} ).

**Question:**
Why **function public function edit($designCode)** is call twice when user is redirected to edit page (or reload this page after create new design ) ?

**Notes:**
This project, I'm using:

1. Apache server
2. Laravel 5.8.*

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in some javascript in the view?

Comment: Why are you using that 301 code? It is only intended to use to fix old routes (like when you update your links to change to https form http https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

Comment: @Amarnasan, Thank you for your answer, Here problem is I don't understand status 301 deeply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
return redirect()->route('edit-design', ['designCode' => $newDesignCode]);
```

No Need To Pass the 301 again. I believe that might be the cause. Or You can share your edit method. It might contain policies/permission look ups that is causing the double execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
return redirect()->route('edit-design', $newDesignCode);
```

After each HTTP request, the page needs a refresh. It's the standard procedure. If you don't want to refresh the page, you can use AJAX calls and manage events with Javascript.