# Laravel 5.4: controller method is called twice on a redirect to it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-redirect, laravel-controller

I'm encountering a problem where a redirect from one route to another is calling the targeted controller method twice. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127975/why-laravel-method-call-twice-when-using-route-redirect-with-parameters-cod) addresses a similar issue, but the OP passing a 301 status code was deemed to be the issue in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128313), and I'm not specifying any status code. I'm also using the session state for parameters. The relevant code looks something like this:

```
public function origin(Request $request) {
  // Assume I have set variables $user and $cvId
  return redirect()
    ->action('SampleController@confirmUser')
    ->with([
      'cvId' => $cvId,
      'userId' => $user->id,
     ]);
}

public function confirmUser(Request $request) {
  $cvId = session()->get('cvId');
  $userId = session()->get('userId');

  if (is_null($cvId) || is_null($userId)) {
    // This is reached on the second time this is called, as 
    // the session variables aren't set the second time
    return redirect('/home');
  }

  // We only see the view for fractions of a second before we are redirected home
  return view('sample.confirmUser', compact('user', 'cvId'));
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? I don't have any `next` middleware or any of the other possible causes that are suggested in related questions where controllers are executed twice.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not really familiar with Laravel, but have you tried putting a breakpoint into the method to look into what calls it the second time? (Or, alternatively, using `debug_print_backtrace()`?)

Comment: @Jeto Thanks for the comment. Looking through the stack, it's just a bunch of Laravel framework functions, nothing coming from my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried passing values in parameters? Try the below code.

```
public function origin(Request $request) {
  // Assume I have set variables $user and $cvId
  return redirect()->action(
    'SampleController@confirmUser', ['cvId' => $cvId, 'userId'=>$user->id]
);
}

public function confirmUser(Request $request) {
  $cvId = $request->cvId;
  $userId = $request->userId;

  if (is_null($cvId) || is_null($userId)) {
    // This is reached on the second time this is called, as 
    // the session variables aren't set the second time
    return redirect('/home');
  }

  // We only see the view for fractions of a second before we are redirected home
  return view('sample.confirmUser', compact('user', 'cvId'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! There was a reason that I wanted to use session parameters instead, but using normal request parameters seems to prevent the extra redirect call. Any ideas why using session would cause this?

Comment: According to official documention, redirecting to Controller Actions. Parameters are recommended.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions